# query adding and multiplying values

Tags: mysql

My table is as follows

```
int_id      Born         Died
 1          2001          0    
 2          2002          0    
 3          1991          0
 4          1992          0
 5          1987         1995
 6          1986         1993
 7          1985         1998
```

From this, I need the query to only show the dead, determine the age they were when they died and have that value multiplied by 3.

I have been trying to do this using phpMyAdmin but have thus far failed to figure it out. Any help given would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: OT: Use NULL in Died if they're not dead yet, sentinel values are evil.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you try, er... subtracting and multiplying?

```
SELECT 
    int_id,
    Died - Born AS age_died,
    3 * (Died - Born) AS age_died_tripled
FROM my_table
WHERE Died > 0;
```